# cannot run bash.exe in elevated cmd window

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL installed and working perfectly. One little problem I've noticed is that, when I try to run `bash.exe` or `C:\windows\system32\bash.exe` from an **elevated cmd session**, I get the error `'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.
Is this a limitation of WSL?  [image]

Comment: If your unable to launch bash.exe in an elevated prompt then you have a problem with environment variables.  I have no problem on my VMWare VM running WSL from an elevated prompt

Comment: @Ramhound, would you happen to know which environment variables are required? I tried to compare the output of `env` in a normal cmd session and in an elevated cmd session, but I did not find any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem to be that I started the elevated cmd process from [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), and the everything version I was using was 32bit.  Turns of 32bit processes have different environment variables than 64bit ones.

I downloaded 64bit `everything`, started it up, opened a cmd window and it worked perfectly.

I pretty much use `everything` as my program launcher, in this case the `everything` process would be the parent of the `cmd` process.